# value can not be null error in PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to import my csv file into my sql database using like this but I'm not sure why it's saying

```
Exception calling "ExecuteWithResults" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: sqlCommands"
```

even though I don't have Null value in my csv file and also I make sure my table columns to accept null value.

```
$s =  New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server "server name"
$db = $s.Databases.Item("LitHold")
$csvfile = import-csv -delimiter ";" -path "C:\scripts\LitHold-OneDrive\output\Return\2022-01-12-Return.csv"
$csvfile |foreach-object{
    $query = "insert into DailyReport VALUES ('$($_.MIN)','$($_.MID)','$($_.UPN)','$($_.Change)','$($_.Type)','$($_.HoldValue)','$($_.OneDrive)','$($_.Mailbox)','$($_.Created)','$($_.Modified)','$($_.MultMID)','$($_.Account)','$($_.ExistOD)')"
}

$result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)

# Show output
$result.Tables[0]
```

My csv file

```
//The top one is my columns name and it's already inside my table 
"MIN","MID","UPN","Change","Type","Hold Value","OneDrive","Mailbox","Created","Modified","Mult MID","Account","Exist OD"

"338780228","lzlcdg","lzlcdg@NAMQA.COM","Hold Created","OneDrive and Mailbox","Y","https://devf-my.sharepoint.com/personal/lzlcdg_namqa_corpqa_geuc_corp_com","lzlcdg@NAMQA.CORPQA.GEUC.CORP.COM","1/11/2022 11:38:57 AM","1/11/2022 11:38:57 AM","N","",""
"419150027","lzs8rl","lzs8rl@.corpq.com","Hold Created","OneDrive and Mailbox","Y","https://my.sharepoint.com/personal/lzs8rl_namqa_corpqa_gcom","lzs8rl@namqa.corpqa.geuc.corp.com","1/11/2022 11:39:05 AM","1/11/2022 11:39:05 AM","N","",""
```

Comment: According to your csv you posted, your delimeter is a comma, not a semicolon.

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala thanks for pointing that out and I'll ready fix that but still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Does running: `import-csv -path "C:\scripts\LitHold-OneDrive\output\Return\2022-01-12-Return.csv"` alone return anything?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala It's weired I'm got this error if I run just that one " import-csv : The member "LZ3J1G@CORPQA.GEUC.CORP.COM" is already present"

Comment: Aside... When invoking `ExecuteWithResults` what dataset do you expect to have returned from an `insert` statement?

Comment: You probably also want to have `$result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)`, with `$query` not `$csvfile`, inside your foreach block.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning oh ok fixed that and it work with what Theo suggested but do you know why it's only inserting the last data from my csv even though I have a lot of data inside it?. :(

Comment: What did you change? It sounds like `ExecuteWithResults` is still outside the foreach block so it would only be executing the last value stored in `$query`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Oh It's working now.. Thanks you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't remove the column headers, but double check how they are written.. with **spaces**

Your code ignores those here

`$($_.HoldValue)` --> `$($_.'Hold Value')`
`$($_.MultMID)` --> `$($_.'Mult MID')`
`$($_.ExistOD)` --> `$($_.'Exist OD')`

Either keep the code and rewrite the headers (take out the spaces) or make sure you use the property names according to the headers.

<sup>By removing the column headers, the first line in the csv file wil be used as column headers unless you supply new ones with parameter `-Header`.  Removing headers will cause problems if the same field value is encountered more than once because column headers must be **unique**</sup>

Then there is this line:

```
$result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($csvfile)
```

which should be

```
$result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)
```

AND there is no point in looping over the records of the csv file and inside that loop **overwrite** your query string on every iteration so only the last record wil remain...

Comment: It work, thanks bro. really appreciate it but can I ask you one more question. I have multiple data in my csv file but I'm not sure why it's not inserting all of them and it only insert the last data. ;( (I uploaded tha data above)

Comment: @ziico Please see the last line of my answer. You may want to look up [this](https://park1.no/2019/08/building-a-sql-import-script-in-powershell/)

Comment: I already fixed that in my actual code but it's still inserting only the last data and not all of them. :(any idea why it might be?

Comment: @ziico Please edit your question and show us your fixes. Are you executing the query inside that loop too?

Comment: oh ok ok, I got it now. I still forgot to put the result inside the for loop. hehe Thank you so much for you help. :)